# PowerBI Custom Visuals defaulting (Chiclet Slicer)

Tags: powerbi

So I've been trying out the new PowerBI custom visuals, most specifically the Chiclet Slicer, but there seems to be an issue, at least with the slicer. You can easily change things like the border and general styling of it, but when you go off the dashboard, it goes back to its default state. Has anyone else found this, or found a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. We're aware of this issue and are looking to fix it.